# With find -exec grep, how to print only basename or split filename/line content on separate lines?

Tags: grep, find

I'm looking at source files.  For PureBasic actually, but whatever the language, there are common elements involved. In my case, the command would be cover extensions `pb`, `pbi`, `pbf`, and `pbp`:

```
find . -name "*.pb*" -exec grep -Hnr ... \;
```

The problem is, this can result in very long lines, and too contracted to read easily because they include `full/path/filename.ext:ln#:contents of that line`.

I want to do one of two things:  Either cut off the path completely (last `/` before first `:`) and leave:

```
filename.ext:ln#:contents of that line
```

or split the line so that I have:

```
full/path/filename.ext:    
ln#:contents of that line
```

Either way makes the results more readable. You could even split it where you had:

```
full/path/filename.ext:ln#:  
contents of that line
```

for increased readability. I'm flexible. It can be any of these. It doesn't even have to be limited to a one-line command or these specific commands.

I've tried every technique I could find listed, involving `find`,`grep` and `sed` but I can't get the combo to do exactly what I want.

Answer (score 1):

I assume, from your description, that you are doing this (I broke it into four lines to avoid horizontal scrolling)

```
>tmp.txt;
find . -type f -name "*.pb*" \
     -exec grep -Hn pattern "{}" ";" >>tmp.txt;
cat tmp.txt | more
```

If you are using Gnu find, you can use `-execdir` instead of `-exec`; that will cause the `grep` command to be executed from within the directory of the target file, with the result that the filename will be relative to the directory it is in. (i.e. `./filename.ext`). That's not *quite* what you're asking for, but it's pretty close, and there are other good reasons to use `-execdir`.

```
     -execdir grep -Hn pattern "{}" ";"      # See note 1
```

Another option is to use an intermediate shell to edit the filename label. This requires Gnu `grep` for the `--label` option:

```
     -exec bash -c 'grep -Hn --label="$(basename "$1")" pattern "$1"' \
           _ "{}" ";"
```

That's quite a bit longer and a lot more work for the OS, but it does eliminate the `./`.

For the second option, you can pipe the entire output through `sed`, inserting a newline after the first (or second) `:` in each line.

```
find . -type f -name "*.pb*" \
     -exec grep -Hn pattern "{}" ";" |
sed 's/:/&\n/' >>tmp.txt.
```

or (second colon):

```
find . -type f -name "*.pb*" \
     -exec grep -Hn pattern "{}" ";" |
sed 's/:[^:]*:/&\n/' >>tmp.txt.
```

#### Notes

1. There is no point telling grep to do a recursive search (`-r`) because you are never giving it a directory as an argument. `find` has already recursively found all the files. So I removed the option from all my examples.
2. `cat tmp.txt | more` is Useless Use of Cat (UUOC). Just use `more tmp.txt`.
3. With Gnu find replace `;` with `+` for more efficiency (except in the example which uses `bash -c`).

Answer (score 1):

Starting from the premise that you want to search for *PATTERN* in your files, here are solutions for each of your suggested layouts:

1. Remove the leading pathname component

   ```
   find . -name '*.pb*' -type f -execdir grep -Hn 'PATTERN' {} \; | cut -c3- >tmp.txt
   more tmp.txt
   ```

   When using `execdir` the program it references is always called from the target directory, and the current file's pathname starts with `./`. The `cut -c3-` simply removes the leading `./` from the pathname.
2. Split the line with pathname, followed by line number and match

   ```
   find . -name '*.pb*' -type f -exec grep -Hn 'PATTERN' {} \; | sed 's/:/:\n/' >tmp.txt
   ```
3. Split the line with pathname and line number, followed by match

   ```
   find . -name '*.pb*' -type f -exec grep -Hn 'PATTERN' {} \; | sed 's/^\([^:]*:[^:]*:\)/\1\n/' >tmp.txt
   ```

   Here, the `sed` pattern splits at the second colon (the RE reads as *Start at the beginning of the line. Match zero of more non-colon characters followed by a colon. And again. Now replace that match with itself and then a newline*).

None of these solutions will work well if your filenames contain colons or newlines.

Answer (score 0):

You could try with `awk` instead of `grep`, e.g. print only basename:

```
find . -name '*.pb*' -exec awk 'function basename(file) {
sub(".*/", "", file)
return file
}
/pattern/{
print basename(FILENAME)":"FNR":"$0
}' {} +
```

and to split path/line content:

```
find . -name '*.pb*' -exec awk '/pattern/{print FILENAME"\n"FNR":"$0}' {} +
```

or

```
find . -name '*.pb*' -exec awk '/pattern/{print FILENAME":"FNR":\n"$0}' {} +
```

If you want to print the filename only once, followed by all matching lines in that file, with two `grep`s:

```
find . -name '*.pb*' -exec grep -l pattern {} \; -exec grep -n pattern {} \;
```

These should work OK with all kind of file names (even with those that contain colons)...

Answer (score 0):

use `grep -l`

```
find . -type f  -exec grep -ilHn --color=always 'searchphrase' {} \;
```

Comment: this does _not_ answer the question; it will print only the (full path) file name not the matching lines - please read the question before posting answers

Comment: right i agree i overlooked it.